# What does "make the whine" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

[The Longman Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/close-relation-relative) has an example sentence that confuses me:

> All of its close relatives except one **make the whine but not the chuck**.

What does "make the whine but not the chuck" mean in this context? No part makes any sense to me.

Comment: I've never hear this expression either. I have no idea what that would mean. I wonder if anyone knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an expression or any kind of figure of speech.  'Whine' and 'chuck' are parts of the mating call of certain types of frogs.  Here's a video where you can hear both:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5S-RAgudnww

The whine is the longer part of the mating call, and the chuck is the clicking bit at the end.

Answer (score 1):

[Here you go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%BAngara_frog)

Apparently the male Tungara frog has two distinct sounds in its mating call:

> Males produce a call that consists of a **whine**, and can also add up to seven short **chuck** sounds to their mating call. A call consisting of both a **whine** and a **chuck** is considered a complex call.

[The mating calls of the Tungara frog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UoUL-jGgU1I)

Here "whine" and "chuck" are [onomatopoetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia) representations of the sounds you hear in the video, and are not directly related to any other meaning of these words.

Comment: Very detailed answer! Thank you! I picked the other answer only because that person has a lower reputation score, and you are already an established user here.

Comment: @EddieKal  It's all the same to me, as PMV's answer is equally correct -- but you really should pick the response that you feel **best** answers your question.  Other things like reputation should not be relevant.